# Reference issue across sheets for looping active cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to combine the following 2 subs to loop through a range, take the value in sheet 4 active cell and 'contains' auto filter that value in sheet "database".

It's a reference issue as the Autofilter line is the one that errors.

Here is the code:

Option Explicit

```
Sub Test2()
Dim searchedvalue As Range

Sheets("4").Select
  Range("A2").Select
  'Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
      Call FILTER1
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Loop
 End Sub

Sub FILTER1()
    Dim searchedvalue As Range
    Set searchedvalue = Sheets("4").ActiveCell.Selection
    Sheets("Database").Range("q2").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="=*" & searchedvalue.Value & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

I have this 'Object doesn't support this property or method' error on last line. The value of the cell that is being filtered is a range that is sequentially moved down the A column od sheet "4"

Comment: It's not the last line, it's this one: `Set searchedvalue = Sheets("4").ActiveCell.Selection` A worksheet doesn't have an `ActiveCell` property - only the `Application` does - so you can only refer to the active cell on the active sheet.

Comment: @Rory How can we refer to the cell that **used to be Active** on an arbitrary worksheet?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent You either have to store a reference to it when it's activated, or activate the sheet, get a reference to it, then carry on.

Answer (score 0):

Well done for using `Option Explicit` but you run into problems using the `Select` method and the `ActiveCell`. Instead, use a `Range` variable, like this:

```
Sub Test2()

Dim targetCell As Range

    Set targetCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("4").Range("A2")
  'Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
  Do Until IsEmpty(targetCell)
      Call FILTER1(targetCell)
      Set targetCell = targetCell.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
  Loop
 End Sub

Sub FILTER1(ByRef searchedCell As Range)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Range("q2").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="=*" & searchedCell.Value & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

Presumably, you have some other code that does something in `FILTER1` with the data after the autofilter has been applied?